# Adding users in a list in Exact target Marketting cloud

Tags: ssjs, landing-page, marketing-cloud

I am trying to add a subscriber to a custom list in my child account in a landing page using SSJS. I have followed the examples given in the Exact target support document and I could able to update a user in a list but couldn't add. I get status as Error. Below is the code that  I have used.Where could be the error?

```
var newSubscriber = {
"EmailAddress": "test.008@example.com",
"SubscriberKey": "20100730001",
"EmailTypePreference": "Text",
"Attributes":{"First Name": "test.008", "Last Name": "test.008" },
"Lists": {"Status": "Active", "ID": 12345, "Action": "Create"}
 };
 var status = Subscriber.Add(newSubscriber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct and it would add always `NEW Subscribers` in All Subscriber list as well List.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var newSubscriber = {
                        "EmailAddress": "test@example.com",
                        "SubscriberKey": "test@example.com",
                        "EmailTypePreference": "Text",
                        "Attributes":{"First Name": "test.008", "Last Name": "test.008" },
                        "Lists": {"Status": "Active", "ID": ListID, "Action": "Create"}
                    };
 var status = Subscriber.Add(newSubscriber);
 Write(status);
</script>
```

You can use Upsert function and it will updates a subscriber if subscriber currently exists in the account, If the subscriber does not exist, it will be added.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var newSubscriber = {
    "EmailAddress": "test@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "test@example.com",
    "EmailTypePreference": "Text",
    "Attributes":{"First Name": "test.008", "Last Name": "test.008" },
    "Lists": {"Status": "Active", "ID": ListID, "Action": "Upsert"}
};

var subObj = Subscriber.Init("test@example.com");
var status = subObj.Upsert(newSubscriber);
</script>
```

Also, [SSJS List](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/list_server_side_javascript_functions/) function also allow to add the subscribers into the particular lists.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var myList = List.Init("ListExternalKey");
  var status = myList.Subscribers.Add("test@example.com");
  Write(status);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.I was able to add subscribers to list only when I add value to a particular attribute.The attribute is "isSubscribed" i don't know why the list is expecting this value.

Comment: Maybe isSubscribed profile attribute is required field in your Profile Management. Please check and unchecked the required field check box.

Comment: I have checked that but its not a required field.